# Variable that can take one of three options in a string (MATLAB)?

Tags: string, matlab

I am trying to load files sequentially in a loop for a long function. My files were of the form var1_var2.mat

My loop is structured in the form of:

```
directory = place

for var= 1 : somebound
    for var2= 1: someotherbound
        curFname = [directory in2str(var1) '_' in2str(var2) '.mat'];

        load files and do stuff 

    end
end
```

However, I have changed my naming convention to where a group of files can have a third underscore, which can be a 1, 2, or 3 depending on certain conditions that the data was taken from.

So now my files are formatted from 1_1.mat to say 1_1_3.mat

How do I create a third character in my curFname = [...] line of code that can take a varying third term 1, 2, or 3? It needs to be defined as variable because there is not 1_1_1.mat, 1_1_2.mat, and 1_1_3.mat, maybe just a 1_1_1.mat

Example, There could be a 1_2_3.mat. but not a 1_2_1.mat or a 1_1_1.mat

Comment: Can't you just use try/catch or check if file exists?

Comment: start with `dir('*.mat')`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by try/catch, this way :

```
success = false;
for it1 = 1:range1
    for it2 = 1:range2
        for it3 = 1:3
            filename = strcat(int2str(it1), '_', int2str(it2), '_', int2str(it3), '.mat');
            try
                load(filename);
                success = true;
            catch
                continue;
                success = false;
            end
            if success
                %do some amazing stuff
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Another way to do it is to get all the .mat files and load them

```
files = dir('*.mat');
for file = 1:length(files)
    load(files(file).name);
    %do some even more amazing stuff
end
```

If there are other .mat files in the directory and you don't want to load them, then you can just use a regexp :

```
files = dir('*.mat');
for file = 1:length(files)
    filename = files(file).name;
    if regexp(filename, '[1-9][0-9]*_[1-9][0-9]*_[1-3].mat')
        load(filename);
        %do some even more amazing stuff
    end    
end
```

If you don't know `regexp`, it matches a string pattern on another string, you will find more on the [MATLAB Doc](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html?searchHighlight=regexp). In my example,

> `[1-9]` is any digit between 1 and 9
>
> `[1-3]` is the same with 3
>
> `*` means that the previous character **can** be present once or more. So `[0-9]*` is `nothing` `[0-9]` or `[0-9][0-9]` or `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`, etc.
>
> You can find more about MATLAB regular expressions [here](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html)

**EDIT :**

I'm not doing `[1-n]` because of the particular syntax of regular expressions. It's a bit hard to explain but will do my best :

`regexp` match **characters**, by typing `[1-x]`, I basicly saying to MATLAB "I want a character which character code is between the character code of 1 and the character code of x". So typing `[1-9]` makes sense.

In an other hand 10 or 25 or any number superior to 9. Let's take **39** as an example. 39 is not a character, **it is composed of 2 characters**. So matching 39 in a regular expression is matching 3, then 9. So `[1-39]` won't work, but `[1-3][0-9]|[1-9]` will.

Comment: I would definitely go for the regex-version. If you mention regex in this context, it would be good to tell that a range 1 to n is not just `[1-n]`.

Comment: Yup, it did seem obvious when I wrote this as long as I was using `+`, but you raise a good point

Comment: Working with the + is fine in my opinion. To your edit: For a range, you need to cover all the possibilities. So for example 1-35 would be `(3[0-5]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])`.

Comment: forgot the 0 case, my bad

Answer (score 0):

The dir command is valuable for such things - you get a cell array full of strings within a certain folder.  Much like in an OS, you get information like file name, last date modified, and so on.

Given this, I believe the answer to your problem lies in control flow i.e. using conditional statements if, while, or whatever suits your need.  For example:

```
for var = 1 : somebound
    variable = dir('foldername');
    if (check your strings and process) ...
```

And so on.  Essentially, you will need the many helpful MATLAB string commands like strfind, strcmp, and strlen.  Arrange your logic to meet your formatting.

Comment: How can I write an if statement in the form of 

    if(file = conditions)? I know how to write the conditions, but how do I reference an ambiguous file?

Comment: You should have a few external for loops to go through each number for each place.  Look at your example 1_2_3.mat.  Your first loop can check for the first place, which is 1 here (and since Matlab treats strings as arrays of characters, you check for the first character here).  If the array holds that, you do two more for loops, one each for the next number (2, the third character) and the next (3, the fifth).  It sounds to me like your files are not "ambiguous" since they have a naming convention.  As you run through your loops, you increment through 1-9 to check all possible numbers.

Comment: Beyond this advice I might not be the most help; you should wait and see if a better answer crops up.  GL;HF!